Best way to solve a multi-class thresholding problem?
I have a multi-class classification problem, where I classify my images into n classes and also a background class. I am currently trying to figure out how to find the optimal thresholds (for each class) that will let me achieve the highest accuracy (So looking at a confusion matrix, I'm trying to maximize the sum of all elements in the main diagonal). The thresholds serve the purpose where if for a detection, the confidence for class p is smaller than the threshold for class p, the detection is deleted.
So I know that for the binary case, you can use ROC curves to figure out the optimal threshold. But I'm not certain if I can do this for every class and then simply combine all the individual thresholds I get?
Any insight would be appreciated.

Are you sure you want to maximize accuracy? See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352.
